# How to interpret flight schedule data from before 1987

Tags: flight-schedules

I'm trying to interpret schedule data from before 1987 (see example).

**Example line:**

```
                                                                                                                   
20100001409B000 033504140079100000000000000000D004BOSJFK  RC0970AS     1234567  0535 BOS 0654   JFK RC 970 YQ   CVR 1           \
```

I'm trying to understand if this flight represents a **direct flight**.  Specifically, my understanding is that the `9B` (byte 11-12) indicates that it is a "**certified direct flight**". However, the `1` (byte 117) after the `CVR` (bytes 113-115) seems to indicate the **number of stops**, here **more than zero**. **I'm trying to figure out what it means if a direct flight has stops**. Some of these "certified direct flights" in my data have more than 4 stops on a short route that would not have needed a refueling stop.

Does anyone have experience in interpreting these older schedule files?

Comment: There is a distinction between a [direct flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_flight) and a non-stop flight. Is that the source of the confusion?

Comment: In short, direct flight means one flight number, nothing else. In particular, and somewhat counter-intuitively, it doesn't mean no stop or even no change of aircraft.

Comment: Is this by any chance a crew roster/schedule?

Comment: @NeanDerThal, it is a set of information about scheduled flights.

Comment: From which tool/system does that come from?